# Print a string from a pointer in C

Tags: c, string, pointers

I have a dynamically sized CHARS array, I'm trying to print the string, using pointers.
I tried something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char *str = NULL;
    int size = 0;
    int c, i;

    printf("Please enter your command\n");
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        {
            str = (char *)realloc(str, size + 1);  
            str[size++] = c; 
        }
    str = (char *)realloc(str, size + 1);  
    str[size] = '\0';  
    free(str);
    
    printf("\nThe size is %d\n", size);

    /* here I want to print the string */
    for(i = *str; i!='\0'; i++){
        printf("%c", *str+i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code does not print the string. The topic of using pointers is not really clear to me, so I think there is my mistake.

Comment: After this statement free(str); the following code does not make sense.

Comment: When you pass a pointer to `free`, the pointer becomes invalid. You should not dereference the pointer again, until you make it point somewhere else.

Comment: Also, `for (i = *str; i != '\0'; i++){ printf("%c", *str+i); }` looks totally random. You put the first `char` in `str` in `i` and then increase `i` until it becomes equal to `\0` ... that may take a while. `i` is signed and signed integer overflows comes with undefined behavior

Comment: Also note that `*str+i` is the same as `str[0] + i` which doesn't make much sense. The loop in itself doesn't make sense either, where you initialize `i` to be the first character of the string. Then you increase `i` which (for ASCII) means that e.g. `'a'` becomes `'b'`. Increasing `i` doesn't make it point to the next character in the string. Either use `i` as an *index* into the string, to be used as `str[i]`, or use a pointer like `for (char *ptr = str; *ptr != '\0'; ++ptr) { putc(*ptr); }`

Comment: `str = (char *)realloc(str, size + 1);` it's extremely expensive to just resize every iteration like this

Answer (score 2):

You deallocated early allocated memory

```
free(str);
```

So after this statement the pointer `str` is invalid and accessing memory using the pointer invokes undefined behavior. You need to free the memory when the allocated character array will not be required any more.

This for loop

```
/* here I want to print the string */
for(i = *str; i!='\0'; i++){
    printf("%c", *str+i);
}
```

does not make sense. In this for loop the variable `i` that stores the code of the first character of the string stored in the dynamically allocated array is incremented. For example if the first character of the string is `'A'` that is in ASCII `65` then after the first iteration it will be equal to `66` that corresponds to the character `'B'`. And the expression `*str + i` will look like `'A' + 'B'` that is the same as `65 + 66`.

If you are going to outputted the stored string using a pointer then you should write for example

```
/* here I want to print the string */
for ( const char *p = str; *p != '\0'; ++p ){
    printf("%c", *p);
}
putchar( '\n' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `free` the memory when you do not need it anymore.

Move `free(str)` to the end of main.

Also `printf("%c", *str+i);` is wrong. You need to `printf("%c", *(str+i));`

You do not check the result of realloc.

```
           char *tmp;
            tmp = realloc(str, size + 1);  
            if(tmp)
            { 
                str = tmp;  
                str[size++] = c; 
            }
            else
            { 
               /* handle error */ 
            }
```

+++ more issues so I will post the working code:

```
int main(void){
    char *str = NULL;
    size_t size = 0;
    int c;
    size_t i;

    printf("Please enter your command\n");
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        {
            char *tmp;
            tmp = realloc(str, size + 2);  
            if(tmp)
            { 
                str = tmp;
                str[size++] = c; 
            }
            else
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    str[size] = '\0';  
    
    printf("\nThe size is %zu\n", size);

    /* here I want to print the string */
    for(i = 0; str[i]; i++){
        printf("%c", *(str+i));
    }
    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @jvx8ss because you had mouch more issues in the code.